# Rmarkdown: Is there a function to create .Rmd documents?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using Rstudio, one can use `File -> New File -> R markdown...` to create a new R markdown file from a template, with YAML headers and some examples already buffered. Is there a function to replicate this without an IDE (in this case, saving the template Rstudio would buffer in a new file)?

I'd rather start my .Rmd file from template rather than from scratch, but not using an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rmarkdown::draft` seems to do what you want. It creates a new file, based on a template. You can provide a link to a custom template. See the help page for details.

Comment: This is what I needed! One additional question: where are the "standard" `html_document` and `pdf_document` templates? If I set the argument to `template = "pdf_document"` it returns an error message that the template was not found in the `rmarkdown` package. It does work when using templates from other packages.

Comment: I don't know. Poked around [the rmarkdown templates folder](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/tree/master/inst) and didn't see it. Could be in another package. The RStudio support forums might be able to help better with that detail. (Or ask another question here specifically for that.)